# In the mean value theorem, we are guaranteed $c$ such that $f'(c) = (f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)$. Does $c$ have a name?

Tags: calculus, terminology, math-history

The Mean Value Theorem says approximately that for differentiable $f$, there is a $c \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
f'(c) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b - a}.
$$
I presume that the number $f'(c)$ is the *mean value*. My question is very short, and very simple. Is there a name for the $c$ guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem? If I had to name it now, I would call it the *mean value abscissa?*

Many of these classical theorems were proved before the current language of calculus. This means it is possible, perhaps even likely, that such a $c$ was originally given a name.

Comment: Well, one issue is that $c$ need not be unique.  $c$ is just an element of ${f'}^{-1}\left( \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right)$, which need not have size $1$.  For example, consider $x\mapsto \cos x$, and take the interval $(-27,27)$.  There are several elements $c$ in $(-27,27)$ such that $-\sin c=f'(c)=\frac{\cos(27)-\cos(-27)}{27+27}=0$.  Because of this non-uniqueness, the best you could call it is *a* mean value abscissa, with your terminology.

Comment: There is no name, as far as I know, because $c$ is not necessarily unique.

Comment: @Bernard the fact that there may be many local minima does not stop the local minima from being a named phenomenon.

Comment: Of course, but most of the times, one never knows anything about $c$, and what's most useful is to know it is bounded. There is no equivalent for mulmtivatiate  functions. So I guess this explains why it has no name.

Comment: We can call it the number for which the average rate of change from a to b is the same as the slope at x=c. :p

Comment: I'm well aware that $c$ is not necessarily unique. Yet we name non-unique elements all the time.

Comment: @Bernard There is an equivalent for functions $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$, in case you were wondering. Where the interval swapped for a region $U\subset \Bbb R^n$ such that all points on the boundary of $U$ corresponds to co-hyperplanar points on the graph of $f$ in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$, and you look for tangent-hyperplanes parallel to that one. Anyways, you are right, the $c$ itself is often useless apart from its existence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After asking around for a while, I've decided that perhaps $c$ never did get a name of its own for any particular pair $(a,b)$. However, some authors in the 18th and 19th centuries gave a name to a related object:
$$ f'(\theta_h) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},$$
and called $\theta_h$ **Rolle's Function.** However I should note that $\theta_h$ is not generically a function; and although it clearly also depends on $x$, it doesn't seem to be customary to include any explicit dependence in the notation.

In a [cute paper written](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.02558) with a colleague and to appear in the American Mathematical Monthly, we've decided to keep the name *mean value abscissa*.